# Display Image from RSS Feed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rss

I'm parsing an RSS feed using [rss-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rss-parser), displaying the results in a list.

The data is added to the state as such:

```
async getJobsData() {
    let feed = await parser.parseURL(
      "https://weworkremotely.com/categories/remote-design-jobs.rss"
    );

    this.setState({ data: feed.items });
  }
```

The text fields are easy, as these come in as `<pubDate>Mon, 20 May 2019 10:36:42 +0000</pubDate>`, and are added to their respective list items using `<span key={index}>{data.pubDate}</span>`.

The response for images is formatted differently though. It's inserted into the generic `content` response, as the first item.

```
title: [...]
pubDate: [...]
content: "<img src="https://we-work-remotely.imgix.net/logos/0015/7503/logo.gif?ixlib=rails-2.1.3&w=50&h=50&dpr=2&fit=fill&auto=compress" alt="Logo.gif?ixlib=rails 2.1" />
```

How would I extract only the URL (`https://we-work-remotely.imgix.net/logos/0015/7503/logo.gif?`) from that field?

Comment: Start by using `console.log` to figure out what JavaScript data structure rss-parser is generating from that. Looking at the raw XML when you don't know what rss-parser is doing internally isn't going to help much.

Comment: @Quentin Edited the initial question to show the rss-parser output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to parse the text representation into a DOM.

The code snippet below will print `img.src`.

```js
const imgText = `<img src="https://we-work-remotely.imgix.net/logos/0015/7503/logo.gif?ixlib=rails-2.1.3&w=50&h=50&dpr=2&fit=fill&auto=compress" alt="Logo.gif?ixlib=rails 2.1" />`
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(imgText, 'text/html')

console.log(doc.body.firstElementChild.src)
```

Comment: Glad to be of help~

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML parser e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-html-parser and get the src attribute.